# Auto populate few fields in Sitecore MVC custom forms

Tags: mvc-forms

I built a custom form with Sitecore MVC, which has an email field section, however, if a user is logged in, i want the user email to be auto populated in the email section.

How can i get the email of the currently logged in user in Sitecore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it depends where you are storing the email.

### Using xDB

If its in the xDB facet, what key did you store the email under. If you stored it under `Work Email`, you would retrieve it like this.

```
if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact != null)
{
    var emailFacet = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<IContactEmailAddresses>("Emails");
    //Check if an work email address already exists for the contact
    if (emailFacet.Entries.Contains("Work Email"))
    {
        IEmailAddress email = emailFacet["Work Email"];
        return email.SmtpAddress;
    }
}
```

### Using user's account

If you identified the user by their email address.

```
var email = Sitecore.Context.User.LocalName
```

### Using user's profile

If you put the email on the user's profile when you created the user.

```
var email = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.Email
```